# Node and standard glob patterns

Tags: node.js, git, gitignore

How would I use standard glob patterns in a .gitignore file to ignore the node_modules and scss directories and all .json files in all my project sub-directoies?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Node.gitignore) boilerplate, it should be a good starting point. Also, add the following.

```
# SCSS directory or files into it
scss
scss/**/*.scss

# JSON files in sub-directors
**/*.json
```

Answer (score 1):

To minimize the answer of @federico-dondi, adding the following lines to .gitconfig should do the trick:

```
node_modules/
scss/
**/*.json
```

Hope This helps!